# Google Calendar Ical URL for public calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

If I can see a known public google calendar, am i able to figure out the ical feed for it? Or must they specifically provide a link to it that google generates?

Comment: Once you see the public calendar on your calendar, then in calendar settings of this calendar->calendar details->calendar address click on ICAL which generates link in ics, which can be shared with others.

Comment: thats if you are the calendar owner?

Comment: If its public calendar and if its shared with you,then you can see it in your calendar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a third party service, and not directly about programming.

Answer (score 2):

the src address in an embed link - either email or calendar group account (`randomhash@group.calendar.google.com`) - is part of the ical url

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=info@example.com`

to

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/info@example.com/public/basic.ics`

This is not mentioned in googles official help article for sharing public calendars [support/calendar#37083](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083) as of writing, though I sent feedback.